# Multiplying values in a column with different multipliers in excel

Tags: excel

How do I multiply the values in column D with certain values based on column E, such as if the value in column E is 2, then the corresponding values in column D would be multiplied by 100.

[image: Multiplying values]

Comment: Use the If statement [http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-if-statement/]

Comment: Either use nested IF statements; `D2*IF(E2=2,100,IF(E2=3,150,0))` or you could use a range.  You would create a table that has the value in E and the multiplier, then you could use a vlookup; `D2*VLOOKUP(E2,table,2,False)`

Comment: Thanks , the first way worked, but how would I change the formula to add two more arguments such as E2=4, 200 and E2=5, 250. I tried to do it but is says that I've entered too many arguments.

Comment: Just keep chaining if statements `D2*IF(E2=2,100,IF(E2=3,150,IF(E2=4,200,IF(E2=5,250,1))))`

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it.